# (C#) How to transfer funds from myetherwallet to coinbase

Tags: myetherwallet, coinbase

I need to transfer funds from myetherwallet to coinbase.
I looked at https://infura.io/ and https://developers.coinbase.com/ and https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/web3/#properties-methods-overview but so far no luck.
Can you please point me to the resource for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what kind of advice you are looking for here. Do You need to do this personally, or are you writing software in C# to do this for others?

If you are doing it personally, MEW should have provided you with a mnemonic or private key that you can import into [metamask](https://metamask.io/). Once you've done that, simply copy your coinbase address into the metamask transaction UI and sending should be straightforward.

Otherwise, this should get you going in the right direction. (I havent used nethereum.)

1) get a web3 provider using infura or a local node [like this](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/azure/set-up-blockchain-on-azure/#9-connect-to-your-chain) or [this](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/web3/#web3-constructor).

2) ask the user for their intended destination address (don't use the coinbase api)

3) use [web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction) to send funds using their desired signer. (MetaMask or a local node. This doesn't matter to you.)

Comment: I am trying to write C# code to do this for others

Comment: Added some details that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: <Full Code> using Nethereum.Hex.HexTypes;
using Nethereum.Web3;
using Nethereum.Web3.Accounts;
using Nethereum.Web3.Accounts.Managed;

Account account = new Account(<privateKey of transfering account>);
Web3 web = new Web3(account, "https://mainnet.infura.io/<api key>");

HexBigInteger amount = new HexBigInteger(new BigInteger(1000000000000000)); /* Equivalent to 0.001 ETH */
string result = await web.Eth.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAsync(<public address of transfering account>, <public add of receiving account>, amount);</Full Code>